# Role of empty string in ambiguous grammar?

Tags: context-free-grammar, context-free-language

I'm a bit confused by the role of the empty string in this ambiguous grammar:

```
A' -> A
A -> if A B
A -> null
B -> empty string
B -> else S
```

So what does B -> empty string mean/do? Does that mean B could transition to A? And "if", "else", and "null are terminals, then what is the empty string?

Answer (score 1):

It means `B` can be replaced with nothing. The other production for `B` allows it to be replaced with `else S` (although I suspect that's a typo since `S`  isn't defined anywhere).  In other words, in an `if` statement, the "else" clause is optional.

Please note that productions in a context-free grammar are *not* state transitions. If the grammar is regular, then there is a fairly simple way of creating a state machine, but your grammar is not regular; in a regular grammar, no production has two non-terminals.